# what's wrong with my solution?Count of Maximum[Code Chef]

Tags: python

[Question](http://www.codechef.com/problems/MAXCOUNT/).This is simple question yet i don't know what's wrong with this code?

```
from collections import Counter
def com(N,A):
    num_array=A.split()
    c=Counter(num_array)
    C=max(c.values())
    l1=[]
    for k in c:
        if c[k]==C:
            l1.append(k)

    V1=min(l1)
    V=int(V1)
    print V,C

t=input()
for i in range(t):
    N=input()
    A=raw_input()
    com(N,A)
```

If possible any simpler solution would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the values in `l1` to integers before taking the min. Otherwise you are taking the min of strings.

Comment: but i changed it @ V=int(V1)

Comment: You are converting after finding the min.. For instance, try `min(['12','2'])`

Comment: @Ajay, that's usually the case with questions on sites like these. They don't give you all of the tricky cases because they want to challenge you.

Comment: @Ajay, take a look at the other submissions. Python uses a lot of memory just to start up. The lowest I see is 4MB for Python. You might be able to save some memory by just using a dict with a little more code rather than using the Counter class..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25401/discussion-between-ajay-and-justin-peel)

Answer (score 1):

This will get you started:

```
from collections import Counter

li='''2
5
1 2 3 2 5
6
1 2 2 1 1 2'''.splitlines()
c=Counter()
for e in [s.split(' ') for s in li]:
    c.update(e)

print c.most_common(2)
```

Prints:

```
[('2', 6), ('1', 4)]
```